# Get Resources using quota in kubernetes

Tags: kubernetes

After like 2 weeks of running jobs in a namespace with quota, pods stopped running due to insufficient quota but i could not find any running pods

`(⎈ |production:rate-jobs)➜  ~ kubectl get resourcequota -o yaml`

```
apiVersion: v1
items:
- apiVersion: v1
  kind: ResourceQuota
  metadata:
    annotations:
    name: rate-jobs-compute-resources
    namespace: rate-jobs
    resourceVersion: "9644562"
    selfLink: /api/v1/namespaces/rate-jobs/resourcequotas/rate-jobs-compute-resources
    uid: bd2a4c52-0664-11e8-854d-0050568166d0
  spec:
    hard:
      limits.cpu: "4"
      limits.memory: 4Gi
      pods: "2"
  status:
    hard:
      limits.cpu: "4"
      limits.memory: 4Gi
      pods: "2"
    used:
      limits.cpu: "2"
      limits.memory: 4Gi
      pods: "1"
kind: List
metadata:
  resourceVersion: ""
  selfLink: ""
```

`(⎈ |production:rate-jobs)➜  ~ kubectl get pod -n rate-jobs
No resources found.`

As we can see from the above we have a running pod that is taking 2 CPU and 4 Gi but there is no running pod

How can I get what is being used?

Answer (score 0):

By design when Job is done, it stops pods but doesn't terminate them. Keeping them should allow you to still have access to logs of completed pods.

Stopped pods are not shown by command `kubectl get pods`, so you need to use option `-a, --show-all`
For example:

`kubectl get pods -a`

Output:

`pod-name-xyz01   0/1       Completed   0          11m`

To  free resources you can manually remove Jobs with their Pods by using `kubectl delete job <Your_Job_name>` or only Pods by using `kubectl delete pod <Pod-Name>`

Comment: Thanks for the response, but completed jobs/pods should not be counted in quota (this is how it is working). My problem is that no active job/pod as the command show but still quota shows there is one active pod.

Comment: Than could you provide more information about pods.
```kubectl get pods --all-namespaces -o=wide
```

Comment: the quota is done on namespace so viewing other namespaces will not give any value. I did update to v1.9.6 and while updating the issue is cleared and now working as expected. I suspect that for some reason one pod was killed but still counted on quota resources